# Cartoon with three heroes - one strong, one fast and one that could change into animals!

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

This is a children's cartoon from the 80s that was created in the US (I think) and shown on UK television.

There were three main superhero characters - an older man who was super strong, a younger man who was very fast and a third - I think a woman - who could change into animals. They lived in a spaceship and here my memory gets blurry... I *think* that:

- the spaceship had crashed (I don't remember it flying) in a forest
- the spaceship was white
- they exited the spaceship via some kind of tubes at the top

One scene I recall had them trying to break down a door. The strong man pushed on it, the woman changed into an elephant to push on it and the fast man shoulder charged it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you're referring to *[Space Sentinels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Sentinels)*.

> **Space Sentinels** (originally titled **The Young Sentinels** and renamed midway through its only season) is a Saturday morning animated series produced by Filmation which debuted on the American NBC network on September 10, 1977 and ran for thirteen half-hour episodes.
>
> In this series, the Greek mythology figures Hercules and Mercury are joined by Astrea, a character created specifically for the series, to form a superhero team to protect mankind.

....

> - **Hercules**: blonde-haired and blue-eyed Hercules possesses superhuman strength. He was voiced by George DiCenzo, who also voiced Sentinel One and later reprised the role of Hercules in The Freedom Force animated series.
> - **Mercury**: Mercury's power is the ability to run and fly at up to the speed of light. Mercury is of Asian ancestry. He was voiced by Asian American actor character actor Evan C. Kim (who is credited here as simply "Evan Kim").
> - **Astrea**: Astrea can morph into nearly any living animal. She, along with the Super Friends' Black Vulcan, was one of the very few African American superheroes of the era. She was voiced by African American character actress Dee Timberlake.

Comment: Filmation at its low-budget best.

Comment: @DanielRoseman - I *LOVE* Filmation. They're such an integral part of my childhood :)