# 2000s cartoon about a group of heroes with superpowers; one of them could turn into a giant gorilla

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I can't remember the title, but it's a 2000s cartoon. The characters were like secret agents with powers and one of them, probably the main character, could turn into a huge gorilla.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  What was the animation style?  How old were the characters?  How many on the protagonist's team?

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/53553/cartoon-with-three-heroes-one-strong-one-fast-and-one-that-could-change-into?rq=1 is too old

Answer (score 3):

They're not exactly agents, but *[Kong: The Animated Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kong:_The_Animated_Series)* was released in 2000 and Jason often merges with Kong via his cyber-link, which would match with transforming into a gorilla.

> When King Kong fell to his death from the Empire State Building upon being shot down by biplanes in 1933, a scientist named Dr. Lorna Jenkins took DNA samples from him which she used to recreate a clone counterpart of the original Kong with the help of the DNA of her grandson, Jason. Many years later, Dr. Lorna Jenkins sends an e-mail to her grandson where he and his friend, Eric "Tan" Tannenbaum IV are invited to Kong's home on Kong Island. What they didn't know is that their university professor Ramone De La Porta had tampered with the e-mail so that he got invited as well. Upon meeting the native girl Lua, the group is taken to Dr. Lorna Jenkin's lab where Ramone's true colors are shown. Upon getting access to the Cyber-Link technology, Ramone uses it to steal some of the Primal Stones in a plot to take over the world. The Primal Stones were used to keep the fire demon named Chiros in his prison. With the help of his Cyber-Link that can merge him with Kong, Jason and his friends must work to reclaim the Primal Stones from De La Porta and his followers while fighting off the forces of Chiros.

### Intro

### Episode 1